# How to show future months and dates using php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to add a leave list.It should add only 2 years so it should show only 2014 and 2015 that I did. My problem is I have to show Months When he select 2014 it should not show from Jan to May and If he select 2015 it should show Jan to Dec.How I can populate month based on year[image]

In image its showing 2013 please ignore that because my system showing wrong year.

Here is my HTML code

```
    <table>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Add Leave</td>
          </tr>
            <tr>
             <td width="170" valign="middle" height="40" align="left">Date</td>
             <td width="15" valign="middle" align="left">:</td>

             <td><select id="frm_day" name="frm_day">
             <?php 
                for($i=1;$i<31;$i++)
                {
                  echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
                }
            ?>          </select>
             </td>
              <td>
               <select id="frm_year" name="frm_year">
                        <option value="<?php echo date("Y");?>"><?php echo date("Y");?></option>
                        <option value="<?php echo date("Y")+1;?>"><?php echo date("Y")+1;?></option>
               </select>
             </td>
             <td>
             <select id="frm_month" name="frm_month"> 
               <option value="<?php echo date("m");?>"><?php echo date("M");?></option>
             </select>
                 </td>
           </tr>
          <tr>
           <td colspan="3">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What you're describing requires JavaScript.

Comment: why do you have to manually write this? there are alot of date pickers around? sample: your for loop from 31? what happens when its june? it only has 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest one you can get from **[here](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php)**

you can use it then:

```
$timestamp = strtotime("+1 month", yourstartdate);
```

and use it

```
date('Ymd', $timestamp);
```

you have to loop over the future ones:

```
for($i=0;$i < 12; $i++)
{
   $timestamp = strtotime("+".$i." months");
   if(isInFuture($timestamp) && date('m', $timestamp) <= 12) echo date('m', $timestamp);
}

function isInFuture($date, $timestamp = "")
{
   return ($date > date($timestamp));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question `How I can populate month based on year`

Comment: ah sorry, i missed something ;) i'll correct my answer

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the end of your `<body>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentMonth = <?php date('m'); ?>;
    var currentYear = <?php date('Y'); ?>;
    var fullList = document.getElementById('frm_month').innerHTML;

    function changedYear(obj) {
        var selectedYear = obj.value,
            node;

        if (selectedYear == currentYear) {
            for (var i = 1; i < currentMonth; i++) {
                node = document.querySelector('#frm_month option[value='+i+']');
                node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
            }
        } else {
            document.getElementById('frm_month').innerHTML = fullList;
        }
    }
</script>
```

And change:

```
<select id="frm_year" name="frm_year">
```

to

```
<select id="frm_year" name="frm_year" onchange="changedYear(this)">
```

This will remove the months not in the current year if the user selects it. On any other year the full list is restored.

Comment: And a note to the OP: you should still validate the date posted in PHP, as these dates can easily be modified by the user.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest just use a datepicker on this one. One popular datepicker is the `jquery UI datepicker.` Here is an example of what you are trying to achieve:

[**Sample Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/EOn1x0)

This includes the 2 year cap.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<form method="POST" action="">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="10">
        <tr>
            <th width="100" align="left">Date</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="frm_day" id="frm_day" size="1" readonly></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="frm_year" id="frm_year" size="5" readonly></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="frm_month" id="frm_month" size="3" readonly></td>
            <td><img src="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif" id="datepickerImage" style="cursor: pointer;" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#datepickerImage').on('click', function(){
        $("#frm_day").datepicker('show');
    });
    $('#frm_day, #frm_month, #frm_year').datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: '+2Y',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'd/yy/M',
        onClose: function(dateText){
            $(this).val('');
            $('#frm_day').val(dateText.split('/')[0]);
            $('#frm_month').val( dateText.split('/')[2]);
            $('#frm_year').val( dateText.split('/')[1]);
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

> For more info, visit the [**docs**](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjqueryui.com%2Fdatepicker%2F&ei=zO6jU7HLLoL5oAT-nYFY&usg=AFQjCNFzneSJbW5WjAr8-unpZ2lmuTAnJw&bvm=bv.69411363,d.cGU). All the settings can be found there.